# MATLAB: Append strings to make plot

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to make a plot depending on which values are available to plot, my current code looks like:

```
clk=handles.metricdata.clk;
y=handles.metricdata.y;
x=handles.metricdata.x;
input_signal=handles.metricdata.input_signal;
i=1;
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.currentout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}='clk, y';
    i=i+1; 
end
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltageout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}='clk, x';
    i=i+1;
end

if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltagein,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}='clk, input_signal';
    i=i+1;
end

Output_Plot=strjoin(p_out,', ');
Output_Plot
plot(Output_Plot);
```

But the plot fuction cannot understand the input:

```
Error using plot
Invalid first data argument.

Error in RTD_Simulator_Outputs>Run_Plot (line 287)
plot(Output_Plot);
```

The Output of Output_Plot looks like these when all the variables are present:

> clk, y, clk, x, clk, input_signal

EDIT:
Problem is solved thanks proudandhonour and BillBokeey! :)

Here goes a working example with random data for reference:

```
handles.metricdata.currentout='checked';
handles.metricdata.voltageout='checked';
handles.metricdata.voltagein='checked';
clk=[0 0 0.1 0.2 0.1 0 0];
y  =[1 1 1.1 0.9 0.8 1 1]; 
x  =[0 0.1 0 0.1 0.1 0 0.1];
input_signal=[0 0.1 0 0.1 0.1 0 0.1];
i=1;
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.currentout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1; 
    p_out{i}=y;
    i=i+1;
end
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltageout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1;
    p_out{i}=x;
    i=i+1;
end

if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltagein,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1;
    p_out{i}=input_signal;
    i=i+1;
end

plot(p_out{:});
```

Comment: What you're tripping over is that a string is not the same as an argument list. Why not do individual `plot`s in each `if` block, with an initial `hold on` of course to prevent clearing of the axes? Alternatively, if you generate your cell array with the actual variables like `p_out{end+1} = clk; p_out{end+1} = y;` etc. then you can call `plot(p_out{:})`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently passing to the plot function a coma separated list of **strings**, which is different from passing it the coma separated list of **variables** that it needs.

A coma separated list of variables can be obtained by using the column operator **:** from a cell containing your variables. A first step to correct your code would be along the lines of :

```
clk=handles.metricdata.clk;
y=handles.metricdata.y;
x=handles.metricdata.x;
input_signal=handles.metricdata.input_signal;
i=1;
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.currentout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1;
    p_out{i}=y;
    i=i+1;
end
if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltageout,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1;
    p_out{i}=x;
    i=i+1;
end

if strcmp(handles.metricdata.voltagein,'checked')==1
    p_out{i}=clk;
    i=i+1;
    p_out{i}=input_signal;
    i=i+1;
end


plot(p_out{:});
```

This should work, although can't be tested on your particular example as you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)